# Finding variance of columns from 2 dataframes

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes

DataFrame A and Dataframe B.

```
   A <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),b=c(2,4,6,8,10),c=c(3,6,9,12,15),x=c(4,8,12,16,20),y=c(5,10,15,20,25))

 B <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),b=c(2,4,6,8,10),c=c(3,6,9,12,15),x=c(4,8,12,16,20),y=c(5,10,15,20,25))

          A
      a   b   c   x   y
      1   2   3   4   5
      2   4   6   8  10
      3   6   9  12  15
      4   8  12  16  20
      5  10  15  20  25

          B
     a   b   c   x   y
     1   2   3   4   5
     2   4   6   8  10
     3   6   9  12  15
     4   8  12  16  20
     5  10  15  20  25
```

Expected Output:

```
  C
  a   b   c   x   y
  1   0   0   0   0
  2   0   0   0   0
  3   0   0   0   0
  4   0   0   0   0
  5   0   0   0   0
```

Both have a key column which is alpha-numeric.

Both dataframes have 260 columns in all out of which 250 are float.

Is there an eaiser way to easily compute the variance of each of the 250 columns and store the variance in another dataframe?

Comment: You could try `colVars` after placing the dataset in a `list` i.e. `library(matrixStats);lapply(list(A, B), function(x) colVars(as.matrix(x[-1])))`  where I assume the first column as 'id' column

Comment: great thanks. i can specify a range of columns in x correct? if my dataframe has 10 character columns that don't require a comparison?

Comment: How data frame A is related to data frame B? Why are you listing both them if you want to compute the variance independently?

Comment: You can have `x[c("b", "c")]`

Comment: Seems like that approach sums the values and calculates differences. I've updated with expected output. I'm looking for a variance of each individual column. Thanks!

Comment: Also, why are you tagging python here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want difference brtween respective columns of two dataframes

```
temp = names(A)
data.frame(A["a"], do.call(cbind, lapply(temp[!temp %in% "a"], function(x) A[x] - B[x])))
#  a b c x y
#1 1 0 0 0 0
#2 2 0 0 0 0
#3 3 0 0 0 0
#4 4 0 0 0 0
#5 5 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This works. Instead of excluding just "a", can I give a range of columns there?

Comment: Or you can take it easy on yourself and do this if you only want to pick numeric columns A[,which(sapply(A,class) == "numeric")]

Comment: @Bee  If this answers your question,  please consider upvoting and accepting it as an answer.  Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map/mapply` to find the difference between the corresponding columns of 'A' and 'B'

```
cbind(A[1], mapply(`-`, A[-1], B[names(A)[-1]]))
#  a b c x y
#1 1 0 0 0 0
#2 2 0 0 0 0
#3 3 0 0 0 0
#4 4 0 0 0 0
#5 5 0 0 0 0
```

---

Or just

```
cbind(A[1], A[-1] - B[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't cbind merge all the datasets? How do I write out only the variances with the key column to a dataframe?

Comment: @Bee  The variance is calculated using `var` while the difference is with `-` or `diff`

Comment: Yes, thanks, the differences is what i meant. If i were to only write the differences in a separate dataframe, how would i extract them from cbind(A[1], A[-1] - B[-1])